# Error message coming also for correct value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want few numeric text box in my php form like for - Admission No, Distance, Phone No. for this I have written below code which is working fine but problem is when I enter alphabet in any one of the 3 text fields, even if other 2 are having numbers error message displayed for all 3 text box.

How can stop displaying error of correct value text box?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var specialKeys = new Array();
            specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
            specialKeys.push(46); //Backspace
            $(function () {
                $(".numeric").bind("keypress", function (e) {
                    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
                    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
                    $(".error").css("display", ret ? "none" : "inline");
                    return ret;
                });
            });
        </script>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" size="10" class="mandatory numeric" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){echo $_POST['last_name'];} ?>" />

<input type="text"  id="residental_distance" class="mandatory numeric" name="residental_distance" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['residental_distance'])){echo $_POST['residental_distance'];} ?>" />

<input type="text"  id="present_phone" name="present_phone" class="mandatory numeric" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['present_phone'])){echo $_POST['present_phone'];} ?>"/>
```

Comment: What html element has the error class which you are applying that CSS to?

Comment: use jquery ValidationEngine.

Comment: I'm guessing your issue is that you have three error elements, each with the `error` class, and so when you try to display an element with the `error` class, it displays all of them (`$(".error")` will select everything with the error class). If you show me the html that includes your error elements, I might be able to show you how to select and display only the one you want.

Comment: @forgivenson Kindly see the html that includes error element with all the 3 text box like this `<td align="center" width="244">Admission No. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="admission_no" id="admission_no" size="10" class="mandatory numeric" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['admission_no'])){echo $_POST['admission_no'];} ?>" />
    <span class="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Input digits (0 - 9)</span></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is selecting all elements with a class of `'error'`. To just select the `'error'` element connected to the text input that fires the event, change this:

```
$(".error").css("display", ret ? "none" : "inline");
```

To this:

```
$(this).siblings(".error").css("display", ret ? "none" : "inline");
```

This change will first select the current context (the `'numeric'` input field), and find any siblings with the `'error'` class.